# Nvidia card problem. The system is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I just added an Nvidia graphics card 1650 super to my computer, before I just use the CPU integrated graphics as video output.
It seems that I could not get the Nvidia card work properly. I have searched for the problem the whole day and tried a lot of online solutions but none of them works.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 upgraded from 14.04 two years ago with kernel version 4.15.0-111-generic.

Following is the log content in the X.org log file:

[     6.695]
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[     6.696] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     6.696] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-168-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     6.696] Current Operating System: Linux haolinli-desktop 4.15.0-111-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 20:32:34 UTC 2020 x86_64
[     6.696] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-111-generic root=UUID=9aef6acc-88d5-42a2-bb66-d4687fe1d290 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[     6.696] Build Date: 14 November 2019  06:20:00PM
[     6.696] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     6.696] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[     6.696]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     6.696] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,

(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,

(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

[     6.696] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jul 12 11:19:21 2020

[     6.696] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

[     6.696] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.

[     6.696] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.

[     6.696] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     6.696] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""

[     6.696] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".

Using a default monitor configuration.

[     6.696] (==) Automatically adding devices

[     6.696] (==) Automatically enabling devices

[     6.696] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices

[     6.696] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices

[     6.696] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff

[     6.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.

[     6.696]    Entry deleted from font path.

[     6.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.

[     6.696]    Entry deleted from font path.

[     6.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.

[     6.696]    Entry deleted from font path.

[     6.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.

[     6.696]    Entry deleted from font path.

[     6.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.

[     6.696]    Entry deleted from font path.

[     6.696] (==) FontPath set to:

/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,

/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,

built-ins

[     6.696] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"

[     6.696] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.

If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.

[     6.696] (II) Loader magic: 0x55ba68577020

[     6.696] (II) Module ABI versions:

[     6.696]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4

[     6.696]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0

[     6.696]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1

[     6.696]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0

[     6.696] (++) using VT number 7



[     6.696] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration

[     6.697] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)

[     6.698] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:0412:1849:0412 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64

[     6.698] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:2187:7377:2000 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072

[     6.698] (II) LoadModule: "glx"

[     6.698] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so

[     6.699] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

[     6.699]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0

[     6.699]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0

[     6.699] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0

[     6.699] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1

[     6.699] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2

[     6.699] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3

[     6.699] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout

[     6.699] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"

[     6.699] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so

[     6.699] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

[     6.699]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.15

[     6.699]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver

[     6.699]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0

[     6.699] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"

[     6.699] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so

[     6.699] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

[     6.699]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6

[     6.699]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver

[     6.699]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0

[     6.699] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"

[     6.699] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so

[     6.699] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

[     6.699]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4

[     6.699]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver

[     6.699]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0

[     6.699] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"

[     6.699] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so

[     6.699] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

[     6.699]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4

[     6.699]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver

[     6.699]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0

[     6.699] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Fri Apr 21 14:41:17 2017 -0400

[     6.699] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :

[     6.699]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)

[     6.699]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)

[     6.699]    GeForce 256     (NV10)

[     6.699]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)

[     6.699]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)

[     6.699]    GeForce 3       (NV20)

[     6.699]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)

[     6.699]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)

[     6.699]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)

[     6.699]    GeForce 7       (G7x)

[     6.699]    GeForce 8       (G8x)

[     6.699]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)

[     6.699]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)

[     6.699] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms

[     6.699] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev

[     6.699] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa

[     6.809] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19

[     6.809] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting

[     6.809] (II) modeset(1): using default device

[     6.809] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"

[     6.809] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"

[     6.809] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so

[     6.809] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

[     6.809]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2

[     6.809]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0

[     6.809] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 1@0:0:0
[     6.809] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[     6.809] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     6.809] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[     6.809] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     6.809] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     6.809] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     6.809] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[     6.809] (EE) 
[     6.809] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
[     6.809] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     6.809] (EE) 
[     6.810] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

Comment: Have you installed a recent nvidia driver? You seem to be using a very old NOUVEAU driver.

Comment: Hi, I think I installed nvidia-driver-440 through `apt install nvidia-driver-440`, but I am not sure how to use it. How am I able to check the status of the installed nvidia driver?
`nvidia-smi` give:NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.  
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are plenty of answers on here about installing nvidia drivers. Just do a search. You may have to uninstall nvidia packages first and start again. However the very first thing to do is update the software on your installation. sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade. I’d guess there might be a lot to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I have already tried everything I could following different answers, which has already cost me a whole day, but none of them works. I really do not know how where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Read https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04  , maybe this helps.

Comment: Update nvidia dirver from command line.

Comment: Hi Galian, thank for you answer. Unfortunately, I could even not be able to get into the desktop when inserting the new graphic card, it is in the back screen with a window shows "The system is running in low-graphics mode"